# Escaping special characters not working for jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, regex

I have css classNames with special characters (specifically # and +). I wrote a function to format the jQuery selector to escape these special characters with a double backslash. I store the formatted string into a variable and then concatenate it to create the full class name. When putting this into jQuery, the class is not found. But if I hardcode the formatted version of the classname, it works.

Question is, what is going wrong here and how do I select for these class names with these special characters?

Please see the below jsFiddle as an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/w8Lv9e1g/

```
// escape regex to be treated as string literal
function escapeRegExp(string){
    return string.replace(/([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}
// format string to escape character in css
function escapeSpecialChar(string) {
    var specialChar = /[#\+]/g;
    if (specialChar.test(string)) {
        var matchList = string.match(specialChar);
    for (var i = 0; i < matchList.length; i++) {
        var re = new RegExp (escapeRegExp(matchList[i]), 'g');
        string = string.replace(re, escapeRegExp('\\') + matchList[i]);
        }
    }
    return string;
}
var product = 'test-#A1_11dsf14_OBC+SAM';
// this yields test-\\#A1_11dsf14_OBC\\+SAM 
var formatted = escapeSpecialChar(product);

// this doesn't work 
$('.test-' + formatted).text('testing');

// this does work (hard coded)
$('.test-\\#A1_11dsf14_OBC\\+SAM').text('hard coded');
```

Comment: You're ending up with ".test-test-\\#A1_11dsf14_OBC+SAM" because you include the prefix "test-" twice.

Comment: That's not the only issue. The string literal works because the `\\ ` sequence is converted to `\ `, whereas your result has a literal `\\ ` sequence.

Comment: ...seems like you just need to get rid of the loop, and do `string = escapeRegExp(string).replace(/#/g, "\\#");`  http://jsfiddle.net/gwthjhox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
string = string.replace(re, escapeRegExp('\\') + matchList[i]);
```

to

```
string = string.replace(re, '\\' + matchList[i]);
```

and

```
$('.test-' + formatted).text('testing');
```

to

```
$('.' + formatted).text('testing');
```

Edit: Check squint's comment up there for a simpler way of achieving what you want. :)